# deploy zensh/jsgen to appfog

Tags: javascript, node.js, appfog

for appfog I usually use this code:

```
var host = process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

// ...    

}).listen(port, host);
```

Now I found [a very interesting forum software](https://github.com/zensh/jsgen) . Here is the app.js:

```
'use strict';
/*global global, require, process, module, jsGen, _restConfig*/

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    util = require('util'),
    http = require('http'),
    domain = require('domain'),
    serverDm = domain.create(),
    processPath = path.dirname(process.argv[1]);

global.jsGen = {}; // 注册全局变量jsGen
jsGen.version = '0.6.6';

serverDm.on('error', function (err) {
    delete err.domain;
    jsGen.serverlog.error(err);
});
serverDm.run(function () {
    jsGen.conf = module.exports.conf = require('./config/config'); // 注册rrestjs配置文件
    jsGen.module = {};
    jsGen.module.os = require('os');
    jsGen.module.xss = require('xss');
    jsGen.module.then = require('thenjs');
    jsGen.module.marked = require('marked');
    jsGen.module.rrestjs = require('rrestjs');
    jsGen.module.mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
    jsGen.module.nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    jsGen.serverlog = jsGen.module.rrestjs.restlog;
    jsGen.lib = {};
    jsGen.lib.msg = require('./lib/msg.js');
    jsGen.lib.json = require('./lib/json.js');
    jsGen.lib.tools = require('./lib/tools.js');
    jsGen.lib.email = require('./lib/email.js');
    jsGen.lib.redis = require('./lib/redis.js');
    jsGen.lib.CacheLRU = require('./lib/cacheLRU.js');
    jsGen.lib.converter = require('./lib/anyBaseConverter.js');
    jsGen.Err = jsGen.lib.tools.Err;
    jsGen.dao = {};
    jsGen.dao.db = require('./dao/mongoDao.js').db;
    jsGen.dao.tag = require('./dao/tagDao.js');
    jsGen.dao.user = require('./dao/userDao.js');
    jsGen.dao.index = require('./dao/indexDao.js');
    jsGen.dao.article = require('./dao/articleDao.js');
    jsGen.dao.message = require('./dao/messageDao.js');
    jsGen.dao.collection = require('./dao/collectionDao.js');

    jsGen.thenErrLog = function (defer, err) {
        jsGen.serverlog.error(err);
    };

    var redis = jsGen.lib.redis,
        then = jsGen.module.then,
        each = jsGen.lib.tools.each,
        CacheLRU = jsGen.lib.CacheLRU,
        extend = jsGen.lib.tools.extend,
        resJson = jsGen.lib.tools.resJson,
        TimeLimitCache = jsGen.lib.redis.TimeLimitCache;

    then(function (defer) {
        redis.initConfig(jsGen.lib.json.GlobalConfig, defer); // 初始化config缓存
    }).then(function (defer, config) {
        jsGen.config = config;
        if (!jsGen.config.date) { // config缓存未赋值，则从MongoDB取值
            then(function (defer2) {
                jsGen.dao.index.getGlobalConfig(defer2);
            }).then(function (defer2, config) {
                defer2(null, config);
            }, function (defer2, err) {
                // MongoDB无值，初始化数据库
                require('./api/install.js')().then(function () {
                    defer2(null, jsGen.lib.json.GlobalConfig);
                }).fail(defer2);
            }).then(function (defer2, config) {
                each(jsGen.config, function (value, key, list) {
                    if (key in config) {
                        list[key] = config[key]; // 写入config缓存
                    }
                });
                defer(null, jsGen.config);
            }).fail(defer);
        } else {
            defer(null, config);
        }
    }).then(function (defer, config) {
        var api = ['index', 'user', 'article', 'tag', 'collection', 'message', 'rebuild'];

        jsGen.cache = {};
        jsGen.cache.tag = new CacheLRU(config.tagCache);
        jsGen.cache.user = new CacheLRU(config.userCache);
        jsGen.cache.list = new CacheLRU(config.listCache);
        jsGen.cache.article = new CacheLRU(config.articleCache);
        jsGen.cache.comment = new CacheLRU(config.commentCache);
        jsGen.cache.message = new CacheLRU(config.messageCache);
        jsGen.cache.collection = new CacheLRU(config.collectionCache);
        jsGen.cache.timeInterval = new TimeLimitCache(config.TimeInterval, 'string', 'interval', false);
        jsGen.cache.pagination = new TimeLimitCache(config.paginationCache, 'array', 'pagination', true);
        jsGen.robotReg = new RegExp(config.robots || 'Baiduspider|Googlebot|BingBot|Slurp!', 'i');
        jsGen.api = {};
        each(api, function (x) {
            jsGen.api[x] = {}; // 初始化api引用，从而各api内部可提前获取其它api引用
        });
        each(api, function (x) {
            extend(jsGen.api[x], require('./api/' + x + '.js')); // 扩展各api的具体方法
        });
        fs.readFile(processPath + '/package.json', 'utf8', defer); // 读取软件信息
    }).then(function (defer, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data.version = jsGen.version;
        data.nodejs = process.versions.node;
        data.rrestjs = _restConfig._version;
        jsGen.config.info = data;
        redis.userCache.index.total(defer); // 读取user缓存
    }).then(function (defer, users) {
        var rebuild = jsGen.api.rebuild;
        if (!users) { // user缓存为空，则判断redis缓存为空，需要初始化
            // 初始化redis缓存
            then(function (defer2) {
                rebuild.user().all(defer2);
            }).then(function (defer2) {
                rebuild.tag().all(defer2);
            }).then(function (defer2) {
                rebuild.article().all(defer);
            }).fail(defer);
        } else {
            defer();
        }
    }).then(function (defer) {
        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            var dm = domain.create();

            function errHandler(err, res, dm) {
                delete err.domain;

                try {
                    res.on('finish', function () {
                        //jsGen.dao.db.close();
                        process.nextTick(function () {
                            dm.dispose();
                        });
                    });
                    if (err.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                        res.sendjson(resJson(err));
                    } else {
                        jsGen.serverlog.error(err);
                        res.sendjson(resJson(jsGen.Err(jsGen.lib.msg.MAIN.requestDataErr)));
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    delete error.domain;
                    jsGen.serverlog.error(error);
                    dm.dispose();
                }
            }

            function router(req, res) {
                if (req.path[0] === 'api' && jsGen.api[req.path[1]]) {
                    jsGen.api[req.path[1]][req.method.toUpperCase()](req, res); // 处理api请求
                } else if (req.path[0].toLowerCase() === 'sitemap.xml') {
                    jsGen.api.article.sitemap(req, res); // 响应搜索引擎sitemap，动态生成
                } else if (req.path[0].slice(-3).toLowerCase() === 'txt') {
                    // 直接响应static目录的txt文件，如robots.txt
                    then(function (defer) {
                        fs.readFile(processPath + '/static/' + req.path[0], 'utf8', defer);
                    }).then(function (defer, txt) {
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                        res.send(txt);
                    }).fail(res.throwError);
                } else if (jsGen.robotReg.test(req.useragent)) {
                    jsGen.api.article.robot(req, res); // 处理搜索引擎请求
                } else {
                    jsGen.config.visitors = 1; // 访问次数+1
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                    if (jsGen.cache.indexTpl) {
                        res.send(jsGen.cache.indexTpl); // 响应首页index.html
                    } else {
                        then(function (defer) {
                            fs.readFile(processPath + '/static/index.html', 'utf8', defer);
                        }).then(function (defer, tpl) {
                            jsGen.cache.indexTpl = tpl.replace(/_jsGenVersion_/g, jsGen.version);
                            res.send(jsGen.cache.indexTpl);
                        }).fail(res.throwError);
                    }
                }
            }

            res.throwError = function (defer, err) { // 处理then.js捕捉的错误
                if (!util.isError(err)) {
                    err = jsGen.Err(err);
                }
                errHandler(err, res, dm);
            };
            dm.on('error', function (err) { // 处理domain捕捉的错误
                errHandler(err, res, dm);
            });
            dm.run(function () {
                router(req, res); // 运行
            });
        }).listen(jsGen.module.rrestjs.config.listenPort);
        console.log('jsGen start!');
    }).fail(function (defer, err) {
        throw err;
    });
});
```

Do you know how to modify this code to deploy to appfog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[appfog](/questions/tagged/appfog) and [cloudfoundry](/questions/tagged/cloudfoundry) support [auto-reconfiguration](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/08/14/cloud-foundry-now-supports-auto-reconfiguration-for-node-js-applications/) for [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) applications. So the code should run on **AppFog** without any modifications.

However if you want to use those environment variables, you can start by modifying the line `.listen(jsGen.module.rrestjs.config.listenPort);` so it reads:

```
.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT, process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST);
```